# How to display a file that is stored on disk using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel and while reading Dayle Rees's book on [retrieving data](http://daylerees.com/codebright/request-data) I came across this succinct code for files and storing the file on disk.

```
Route::post('handle-form', function()
{
    $name = Input::file('book')->getClientOriginalName();
    Input::file('book')->move('/storage/directory', $name);
    return 'File was moved.';
});
```

My question is how do you display the file that has been stored to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treat the file as a usual file that you would like people to access with a url.

So suppose that your website's public path is at `/var/www/myproject/public`, you will want to move the input file into that folder. For example:

```
Input::file('book')->move('/var/www/myproject/public/uploads', $name);
```

Then you can display your file with a typical HTML `<a>` tag:

```
return 'File was moved. <a href="/uploads/'. $name .'">Access your file</a>.';
```

Answer (score -1):

After uploading the file, you should use Input interface to retrieve the path to your uploaded path. You can get more on it here:

http://laravel.com/docs/requests#files

I will do something like this:

```
Route::post('handle-form', function()
{
    $name = Input::file('book')->getClientOriginalName();
    Input::file('book')->move('/storage/directory', $name);

    $path = Input::file('book')->getRealPath();

    Session::flash("path", $path);

    Session::flash("message", "success");

    Redirect::to("someRoute");

});
```

And then in your Message-Route:

```
Route::get("someRoute", function(){
    if(Session::has("message"))

{
    ?>
    <p>You have successfully uploaded a file. Download <a href="<?php echo Session::get("path"); ?>">your file.</a>
    </p>
    <?php
}
});
```

Comment: Too interesting. Why down-votted?